# jetpack compose remove BottomAppBar select background color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

can i remove BottomAppBer select background color??
I think I just need to erase the oval background
If there's a way to change the icon according to your choice, please recommend that method

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainBottomNavigationBar(navController: NavHostController, currentRoute: String?) {

    val bottomNavigationItems = listOf(
        MainNavigationItem.MainNav.Home,
        MainNavigationItem.MainNav.Leaderboard,
        MainNavigationItem.MainNav.MyPage,
    )

    BottomAppBar {
        bottomNavigationItems.forEach { item ->
            NavigationBarItem(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                onClick = {
                    
                },
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        imageVector = item.icon,
                        contentDescription = item.name
                    )
                },
                colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                    Color.White
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[sampleimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzjVB.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLEKS.png)

setBackgroundcolor but its fail

Comment: You need to replace ```NavigationBarItem``` with you own design.

Comment: Use Material2 BottomNavigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
  indicatorColor = Color.Transparent
)
```